# Is it possible that update a table with results with another nested query which inlude the queried table itself?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two tables. First has id (AI) field and old_id (Int) field.
Second table has a referred field p_id from first tables old_id as a relation point.

I want to update p_id to firstTable.id values. Is it possible to update secondTable.p_id with the value returned from firstTable.id ?

Here is my test sql:

```
UPDATE secondTable sT 
SET sT.p_id = (
    SELECT fT.id 
    FROM firstTable fT 
    WHERE fT.old_id = secondTable.p_id
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update with `JOIN` like this:

```
UPDATE secondTable sT 
INNER JOIN firstTable fT ON fT.old_id=secondTable.p_id
SET sT.p_id = fT.id;
```

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud, i am using MySQLworkbench manager program. And it throws an error. Here it is:
Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Queries and reconnect.

I try to toggle the option mentioned.

Comment: @caglaror - You can also toggle it like this: `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;`